# Way to Implement code from another HTML/CSS file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to HTML development and was wondering if there was a way to structure your code like implementing Java methods.

For example:

```
<ul id = "my-nav">
     <li><a href=clips.html>Clips</a></li>
     <li><a href="moments.html">Moments</a></li>
     <li><a href="media.html">Media</a></li>
     <li><a href=contact_br.html>Contact Me</a></li>
</ul>
```

I will be using that as a navigation bar for all my HTML files I add.

Instead of typing and changing the navigation bar manually every time I need to make a change. Is there a way I can keep the navbar in a separate html or portion where all the others import the information from that source?

Comment: Java or JavaScript? They are (2) different languages.

Comment: You can create header.html where you will have navigation code.. And you can include "header.html" in all other files where you want to call navigation..

Comment: @rhavendc I'm mostly using the HTML language and CSS. I am also using Javascript in my files but I am an extreme novice at it.

Comment: @priyajain Once I create and include the file how / where in my body of the other HTML's will I call the navbar code.

Comment: @vucko Thank you, I think this may work the best for me

Answer (score 0):

You can see how its done [here](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp)

Or you can save the files as PHP files if you want, then you can do a header.php separately with your nav element and then import it on top of all pages

For Example, your header.php file will look like the following

```
<ul id="my-nav">
  <li><a href="clips.html">Clips</a></li>
  <li><a href="moments.html">Moments</a></li>
  <li><a href="media.html">Media</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact_br.html">Contact Me</a></li>
</ul>
```

And then on your page.php file you will call an include on the container where you want to place the header as follows

```
<section class="no-padding it-main-content large-12 columns">    
  <?php include("parts/super-admin-aside.php"); ?>
</section>
```

**NB: you need XAMPP to run PHP file locally**

Hope that helps!